# Making conditions in a Rails 'includes' query dynamic

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What seems like a pretty straightforward task has presented some issues with setting up associations in my Rails app.

I have a model for `Games` that includes a column for `game_start` with a datetime as well as a `category` column that specifies the type of game. The table might look like:

- ID: 1 | 2016-02-24 03:23:00 | Sports
- ID: 2 | 2016-02-25 04:10:00 | Free
- ID: 3 | 2016-02-26 01:23:00 | History

I can show a listing of all available games using `Quiz.all`, sort by `game_start` time, and the like. However, what I want to do is show the user the games that they have *signed up for* in the `Registration` model. This model includes:

- ID | CATEGORY | USER_ID
- 3  | Sports   | 215
- 4  | Free     | 301
- 5  | History  | 215

Now what I want to do is use the controller to **only** return results of future games `(>Time.now)` that the `current_user` has registered for.

```
  @registration = Registration.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists? && Game.where("game_start > ?", Time.now)
```

Despite the `&&` condition, this is returning all future games (I believe the first condition is looking only at if the user has any registered games; if yes, it shows all registered games). I want to filter this to only games in the future that our user has registered for.

After researching, I have discovered that a join table may not be necessary (or a polymorphic association). It seems like maybe I could create this condition using `:includes`.

Would it be feasible to adapt the original controller object to also have something like:

```
  @registration = Registration.where(user_id: current_user.id).includes(category: ???) [...]
```

Both the `Game` and `Registration` table share a `category` attribute. In my example above, is it possible to make the ??? dynamic, such that it looks at the other condition `Game.where("game_start > ?", Time.now)`, returns the `category` attribute, and then uses that category attribute to show Registered games that match.

In my example table, if the `current_user` is 215, it would see two Reservation entries (ID 3 and 5), query the `Game` table, and return only games with a matching category.

Any ideas on how I can use the controller to extract the category and dynamically tell the second condition to query for that same category?

**Game.rb**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registrations
 end
```

**Registrations.rb**

```
 class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :game
  end
```

Comment: So there is no association between `Registration` and `Game` models?

Comment: can you put your model and there association here

Comment: @VishalJAIN - Just added to the OP. Good point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey instead of using `&&` you can used `joins` here as

```
@registrations = Registration.joins(:game).where(user_id: current_user.id).where("games.game_start > ?", Time.now)
```

if you want to load it on view file then use eager loading using `includes` as

```
@registrations = Registration.includes(:game).where(user_id: current_user.id).where("games.game_start > ?", Time.now)
```

And used in you view file as

```
<% @registrations.each do |registration| %>
    <%= registration.game.game_start %>
    <%= registration.category %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, so I can use `joins` here. Then, to iterate in the view, would I just open with `<% @registrations.games.each do |registration| %>`? Just tried it and got an error, but may need to try a few more options.

Comment: hey you are trying to select games on active record relation so this error you used as `@registrations.first.game`

Comment: @darkginger Are you wanting a list of games or a list of the registrations?  Or both the registrations and the games?

Comment: I would say "both" but I'll clarify: I want a list of Games where the current user is Registered for the matching category (which is why I made Registration belong-to the Game model). Good question

Comment: @darkginger you can select `registration` and from registration you can select related `game` updated in answer

Comment: @VishalJAIN Updated to the `@registrations` for the view, but we're getting a weird error for `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: reservations.quiz_id: SELECT "reservations"."id" AS t0_r0, "reservations"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "reservations"."category" AS ` even though we're not using "as". Trying a few different things, will post back if I figure it out. Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: @darkginger `quiz_id` is present in your `reservations` table? and when this error occured?

Comment: @VishalJAIN `Reservation` has a Reservation ID, User_ID, and Category attribute in its table. Quiz has a Quiz ID, Category, and Game_Start time in its table. So the ID columns are named differently and category would be the only shared value between them (referenced in the original post, for more detail).

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
game = Game.first
game.registration
```